# PhantomJS integration testing with angular against live backend

Tags: angularjs, mocking, angularjs-e2e

I am trying to make my e2e test environment to be like the actual production environment. I discovered that when I take out the ngMockE2E from my app and run tests that actually hit the backend server then all my tests in PhantomJS fail. In all other browsers tests always pass.

I'm not sure what the cause of this is. All I know is that when I put the ngMockE2E back in then all tests pass in PhantomJS and when I take it out the tests that depend on the xhttp request fail.

One more thing the live backend is cross origin. But like I said it works fine in all other browsers. I'm wondering if PhantomJS doesn't have cors support.

Does anyone know how to remedy this? Am I supposed to always use the mocks?

Answer (score 0):

For E2E testing with a real back end, I would consider using [Protractor](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/). As far as I know, ngMock and ngMockE2E are both made to fake a connection to a real server. With these libraries you can unit test your Angular project so that it works isolated.

Note that it is a bit more work to setup E2E testing with Protractor if you start from scratch. There are however also starter projects (Yeoman), which already have this setup for you. You could use [generator-angular-gulp](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular) for example for your application, or you could have a look how they have set things up.